# how can I fire up carbon emacs (as editor instead of emacs in default) to edit a file under terminal.app?

Tags: emacs, macos-carbon, carbon-emacs

How to configure the bash file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
alias cemacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app'
```

Then I can type `cemacs foo.txt` and have emacs open the file.

(Is that what you were asking? The question was a little vague.)

Answer (score 0):

> export EDITOR=/usr/bin/emacs

to your ~/.bash_profile